# Frame Region Adapter and RegionContext in Silverlight 3/PRISM

Tags: silverlight-3.0, prism, deep-linking

I'm trying to use the new Silverlight 3 deep linking feature to try to drive a PRISM based application "from the outside", i.e, by using the browser url. The url would be used as a hint to know which PRISM module to load.

So, I have a region hosted inside a SL3 Frame which is adapted by a custom region adapter I built. All the views that I want to show inside that frame provide a NavigationUri, so when I add a view to that region and activate it, the region adapter is smart and starts a navigation from the frame. These views are "lookless", in the sense that they are not really displayed in the region, but serve as a hint to what view should be displayed.

I also have a single page with parameters (similar to 
[this](http://programwith.net/2009/03/23/Silverlight3NdashDeepLinking.aspx)) which is the one that is going to be hosted inside the frame. That page knows which actual view to display by using the parameters I'm passing in the previous step.

The question is, how do I pass contextual information to this catch-all page? Potentially, I need to get hold of the model objects who triggered the navigation in the second step, and  access the services that are registered in the container so I can do some view injection and other dependency injection magic.

I know its maybe a little bit too complicated, and some clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight and Prism, there is one or two people that I have always used for reference,
when I was still doing Silverlight.

You can try this link out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/10/05/integrating-prism-v4-region-navigation-with-silverlight-frame-navigation.aspx

I do suggest one things though, instead of trying to bake this into your application right from the start, I would create my own sample application based upon that which I am trying to implement. Once you have it working, you will know exactly what you need to do in your app.

Karl Shifflett is one of the names that you could look for when searching for help related to
Prism and Silverlight

I hope this helps.

Regards

Louis